# How to kill the currently executing query of a job in sql server 2008r2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs

I'm a SQL Server newbie and I have been given a small task around which I cannot wrap my head. I have to verify that if i kill the query which a sql server job is currently executing will the job continue running indefinitely or it will fail. Creating a small job that runs a long running sql query was easily accomplished, but i cannot get how to identify which task is currently running and kill it. I use this reference 
  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/ 
But it doesnt show me the currently executing queries.

Sorry if this is a really silly question , but any help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the server name and choose Activity Montior.

Alternatively, you can query the process list with:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_requests
```

An even better solution is [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) from Adam Machanic, but that might be overkill for your situation.

Comment: Ok This is what I'm doing, In one window i run this sql statement

select * from emp_detail
go 300

And after executing this, I quickly switch to another tab and execute select * from sys.dm_exec_requests

But there's no indication of the currently running queries in the previous tab. What am i doing wrong? Shouldnt there be an entry for the queries running in the previous tab?

Comment: Should be, except if you query exactly between one of the 300 executions of `go 300`.  Try `waitfor delay '2:00'` for a query that is definitely running.

Answer (score 0):

down and dirty - take the DB offline then online (if possible)